# Run a function on a pandas column with strings and column of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to run several pieces of code on both the "**parent**" column and each element in the "**children**" column lists from below. The results I'm aiming for are in the "**resultsX**" column:

The **first** code (shown in results1 column) snippet just takes two strings and gets the **total unique characters in each**:

```
>>> len(set('max' + 'andi'))
>>> 6
```

The **second** piece of code (shown in results2 column)  counts the number of characters that are in the same position in two strings:

```
>>> sum(1 if c1 == c2 else 0 for c1, c2 in zip('maxwell', ' axwell'))
>>> 6
```

I'd like to run these two pieces of code on the "parent" column and each element in the "children" column and get what's in the **"results1 and results2"** columns respectively:

```
parent           children                       results1                                     results2
0   MAX          ['MAX', 'amx', 'akd']          [('MAX',3),('amx',3),('akd',5)]          [('MAX',3),('amx',0),('akd',0)]
1   Sam          ['Sam','sammy','samsam']       [('Sam',3),('sammy',4), ('samsam',3)]      [('Sam',3),('sammy',3), ('samsam',3)]
2   Larry        ['lar','lair','larrylamo']     [('lar',4),('lair',5), ('larrylamo',6)]  [('lar',3),('lair',3), ('larrylamo',5)]
```

I have tried this code below, but i get an error when i run it:

```
def total_chars(reference, value_list):
    chars = []
    for val in value_list:
        totalChars = len(set(reference + val))
        chars.append(val, reference)
        
    return totalChars

df.agg(lambda x: total_chars(df.parent,df.children), axis=1)

>>> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (10000,) (4,)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: The results column in your example appears to only show results from the first piece of code. Where are the results from the second piece of code? Or is that your problem?

Comment: It seems the last results are in the wrong order? The children input is `['lar', 'lair', 'larrylamo']`, while the results are ordered `['lar', 'larrylamo', 'lair']`. Given that these are inside (ordered) lists, I assume that's just an accidental mistake in the example?

Comment: sorry y'all - fixed all those edits. see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need

```
def cust_func(row):
    results1 = []
    results2 = []
    p = row['parent'].lower()
    for i in row['children']:
        t = i.lower()
        results1.append((i, len(set(t + p))))
        results2.append((i, sum(int(k==v) for k,v in zip(t, p))))

    return pd.Series([results1, results2])
        

df = pd.DataFrame({"parent": ['Max', 'Sam', 'Larry'], "children": [['MAX', 'amx', 'akd'], ['Sam','sammy','samsam'], ['lar','lair','larrylamo']]})
df[['results1', 'results2']]  = df.apply(cust_func, axis=1)
print(df[['results1', 'results2']])
```

**Output:**

```
                                results1                               results2
0         [(MAX, 3), (amx, 3), (akd, 5)]         [(MAX, 3), (amx, 1), (akd, 0)]
1    [(Sam, 3), (sammy, 4), (samsam, 3)]    [(Sam, 3), (sammy, 3), (samsam, 3)]
2  [(lar, 4), (lair, 5), (larrylamo, 6)]  [(lar, 3), (lair, 3), (larrylamo, 5)]
```

Answer (score 1):

No looping over data frame.  Just a function for place wise comparison

```
df = pd.DataFrame([{'parent': 'MAX', 'children': ['MAX', 'amx', 'akd']},
 {'parent': 'Sam', 'children': ['Sam', 'sammy', 'samsam']},
 {'parent': 'Larry', 'children': ['lar', 'lair', 'larrylamo']}])

def placewise(a1, a2):
    s = 0
    for i in range(min(len(a1), len(a2))):
        if a1[i] == a2[i]: s += 1
    return s

df = (df.explode("children")
 .assign(
     results1=lambda x: x.apply(lambda r: (r["children"], 
                                           len(np.unique(np.concatenate([list(r["parent"].upper()), 
                                                                         list(r["children"].upper())])))
                                          ), axis=1),
     results2=lambda x: x.apply(lambda r: (r["children"], placewise(r["parent"].upper(), 
                                                                    r["children"].upper()
                                                                   )
                                          ), axis=1),
 )
 .groupby("parent", as_index=False).agg({"children":lambda x: list(x),
                                         "results1":lambda x: list(x),
                                         "results2":lambda x: list(x)})
 
)

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
parent                children                               results1                               results2
 Larry  [lar, lair, larrylamo]  [(lar, 4), (lair, 5), (larrylamo, 6)]  [(lar, 3), (lair, 3), (larrylamo, 5)]
   MAX         [MAX, amx, akd]         [(MAX, 3), (amx, 3), (akd, 5)]         [(MAX, 3), (amx, 1), (akd, 0)]
   Sam    [Sam, sammy, samsam]    [(Sam, 3), (sammy, 4), (samsam, 3)]    [(Sam, 3), (sammy, 3), (samsam, 3)]
```